# If AUC is 1 can be FNR 0.03?

Tags: auc, false-positive-rate

If AUC (Area under Curve) is 1, do we expect  FNR (False Negative Rate) be 0?
For example, can FNR be 0.03?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FNR has to be $0$ if AUC-ROC is $1$.

That is because for AUC-ROC to equal $1$ we need to have FPR of $0$ at TPR of $1$, as FNR = 1 − TPR, then AUC-ROC to be equal to $1$ we need an FNR of $0$. If FNR was larger than $0$ then we would not get AUC-ROC of $1$ as we could be "lower" in the $y$ axis of the ROC space.